# « Hériter qqch. » vs « hériter de qqch. » ?

Tags: prépositions, compléments

Voilà une phrase que je viens de lire dans le livre « Le paradis d’en bas » d’après Audren :

> Je viens, paraît-il, d’hériter **d**’une maison à Barbizon et **d**’une grosse somme d’argent.

Je ne savais pas que l’on pouvait hériter **de** quelque chose. Moi, j’éviterais la préposition « de », par exemple : *J’ai hérité la maison.*

Est-ce qu’il y a une différence de sens ?

Et deuxièmement, est-ce qu’en conséquence les pronoms personnels et pronoms relatifs changent aussi, comme dans les phrases ci-dessous ?

> – Tu as hérité la maison ? – Oui, je **l**’ai hérité**e**.
>
> – Tu as hérité **de** la maison ? – Oui, j’**en** ai hérité. (?)
>
> – Voilà la maison **que** j’ai hérité**e**.
>
> – Voilà la maison **dont** j’ai hérité. (?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Heureux les débonnaires, car ils hériteront la terre.*
>
> [ *Bible*, traduction de [Louis Segond](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Segond), *Matthieu* 5 ]

Au *LBU* (*Le bon usage*, 14<sup>e</sup> édition, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot, au §285b5°+H12), on explique qu'avec le verbe *hériter* :

- On utilise la préposition ***de*** pour indiquer l'**origine** de l'héritage (comparer avec le substantif [*héritier*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/h%C3%A9ritier), au sens courant, où évidemment on utilise *de* aussi bien pour le bien que pour son origine)
- Si on a uniquement **un** complément sur le **bien**, on peut utiliser
  **avec ou sans** la préposition *de* (n'apparaît pas dans [*Ac.9*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/h%C3%A9riter) ; *sans* étant plus littéraire, vu en particulier l'[origine](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/heriter)<sup>1</sup> latine ecclésiastique où le complément était formé avec l'accusatif, voir [*Vulg.*](http://www.vatican.va/archive/bible/nova_vulgata/documents/nova-vulgata_vt_psalmorum_lt.html#PSALMUS%2025) *Ps.* 24,13 : *semen ejus hereditabit terram* ; *la semence de lui héritera la terre*, au [Psautier de Cambridge](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litt%C3%A9rature_anglo-normande#Litt.C3.A9rature_didactique))
- Si on a **les deux compléments**, quant au bien et à l'origine, on dit
  *hériter qqc. de qqn.* (*hériter qqn. de qqc.*, jusqu'au 16<sup>e</sup> pour laisser qqc. en héritage à quelqu'un)
- *Hériter de qqc. de qqn*, est **rare** et peu recommandable (régimes mixtes) ; moins désagréable à entendre avec *dont* (« *Le maire de Verrières devait une réputation d'esprit [...] à une demi-douzaine de plaisanteries **dont** il avait hérité d'un oncle* », Stendhal, *Rouge*), et encore moins avec *en* (« *L'Italie n'a pas inventé la mosaïque : elle **en** hérita des Grecs.* », Cl. Roger-Marx, dans le *Figaro litt.*)

---

Il est difficile d'avoir une présentation systématique dans un dictionnaire ([*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/h%C3%A9riter) : A. − *Emploi trans. dir.* ou *indir.* Hériter (de) qqc.; hériter (qqc.) de qqn ; B. − Hériter (de qqn)). Une difficulté est qu'on se demande parfois si on a affaire à un complément distinct ou au complément du nom à même l'objet direct unique (*de la maison de ma mère* vs. *d'une maison, de ma mère*). Au *Larousse*, on découpe selon les formes [*transitive*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/h%C3%A9riter/39678?q=h%C3%A9riter#39600), [*transitive indirecte*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/h%C3%A9riter/39676?q=h%C3%A9riter#39598) et [*intransitive*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/h%C3%A9riter/39677?q=h%C3%A9riter#39599), puis on traite de [difficultés](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/h%C3%A9riter/39678/difficulte) :

> ***Hériter qqch, hériter de qqch*** = recevoir par voie de succession. *Il a hérité une très grosse fortune. Elle a hérité de la maison de ses parents.*
>   ***Hériter de qqn*** = recueillir sa succession. *Ils ont hérité de leur grand-mère sa propriété en Provence.*

---

Il existe sans doute des nuances entre le sens juridique d'être [héritier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/h%C3%A9ritier) (avoir vocation à prendre une masse de biens, par la loi) et celui d'être [légataire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/l%C3%A9gataire) (se voir remettre un bien particulier) ; mais *héritier* au sens courant englobe les deux, ainsi que le verbe *hériter*. On peut comparer le dernier exemple au *Larousse* avec ce qui suit, pour fins de réflexion, à savoir peut-on parler uniquement de recueillir la succession d'une personne sans associer le bien qu'on nomme à la personne qui donne :

> J'ai hérité de ma grand-mère ma maison en Provence. [?]

---

**R.** Il y a variation selon le *type* et le *nombre* de complément(s), le *registre*, l'*époque*, et peut-être incidemment selon le *sens*. Enfin, comme on l'a vu, on peut dire *j'ai hérité la maison* ou *j'ai hérité de la maison*.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> On note que c'était aussi bien dans le sens de *donner* que *recevoir* en héritage (12<sup>e</sup>). Ailleurs on précise que ce fut d'abord dans le sens de donner : *donner (qqch.) en héritage à qqn.* Et ensuite dans le sens de recevoir : *recevoir (qqch.) en héritage*. De là provient la construction sans complément direct *hériter de qqn.* au 17<sup>e</sup> (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, dir. A. Rey, ed. *Le Robert*).</sub>

Comment: Les numéros de paragraphes diffèrent d’une édition à l’autre, c’est plus sage de l’indiquer.

Answer (score 4):

La phrase *J'ai hérité la maison* n'est pas une phrase correcte.

On hérite toujours *de* quelque chose : j'ai hérité de mon père, d'une voiture, d'une maison.

Il n'y a pas de différence de sens, puisqu'on comprendra via les deux phrases que vous avez hérité de la maison. Mais d'un point de vue grammatical, il manque la préposition *de*.

> Tu as hérité la maison ? – Oui, je l’ai héritée.

Cette phrase est par conséquent incorrecte également.

> Tu as hérité de la maison ? – Oui, j’en ai hérité. (?)

Cette phrase, elle, est tout à fait correcte.

> Voilà la maison que j’ai héritée.

Même s'il y a des chances de pouvoir entendre ce genre de phrase, elle n'est grammaticalement pas correcte.

> Voilà la maison dont j’ai hérité. (?)

Préférez donc plutôt cette formulation qui est correcte.

Comment: *J'ai hérité de cette maison* et *J'ai hérité de mon père*, mais note que lorsqu'il y a deux compléments, le bien est complément direct : *J'ai hérité cette maison de mon père*.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : oui tout à fait ! J'ai repris l'exemple mentionné où il n'y avait qu'un seul complément. Merci de la précision tout de même.