# « Hériter » : transitif ou non ?

Tags: verbes, transitivité

Suite à la question [« Hériter qqch. » vs « hériter de qqch. » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/16630/635) je suis allé voir le [cnrtl](http://www.cnrtl.fr).

Pour le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/h%C3%A9riter), le verbe *hériter* est transitif.
Pour le [dictionnaire de l'Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/h%C3%A9riter), quelle que soit l'édition, il est intransitif.

Y-a-t'il une explication ?

Comment: Les deux mentionnent à la fois des emplois transitifs (direct) et intransitifs (en particulier, transitif indirect)…