# "La maison, je l'ai héritée de mon père". Cette phrase est-elle correcte?

Tags: accord

"La maison, je l'ai héritée de mon père".Cette phrase est-elle correcte? Ou dois-je dire: "La maison, je l'ai hérité de mon père" ?

Comment: The rule is that if the direct object precedes the past participle, the participle agrees. So if the base form would be "hériter la maison" then you must use agreement in your sentence.

Comment: Side question: is it more common to structure a sentence like this by "Cette phrase est-elle correcte?" or "Cette phrase est correcte?" ?

Answer (score 2):

Hériter est ici transitif direct. L'accord doit être fait car le complément d'objet direct est placé avant le verbe avoir (Tu as hérité quoi ? J'ai hérité la maison):

> **La maison**, je l'ai **héritée** de mon père.

comme avec :

> **La maison** que j'ai **héritée** de mon père.

mais pas d'accord avec « dont » car ce pronom relatif remplace toujours un complément d'objet indirect (Tu as hérité **de** quoi ? J'ai hérité **de** la maison), hériter est ici transitif indirect:

> La maison dont j'ai **hérité**.

voire le parfois controversé :

> La maison dont j'ai **hérité** de mon père.

tournure que Grévisse ne condamne pas et que Stendhal a utilisé :

> …une demi-douzaine de plaisanteries **dont** il avait hérité **d**'un oncle. ***Stendhal***, le Rouge et le Noir.

Voir aussi:

> J'ai hérité **de** lui **d**'un opéra qui était admirable. (Marivaux)

ainsi que cette [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16630/h%C3%A9riter-qqch-vs-h%C3%A9riter-de-qqch).

Comment: hériter de quelque chose, ou hériter quelque chose de quelqu'un. pas de double de -1

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina « …une demi-douzaine de plaisanteries dont il avait hérité d'un oncle. » Stendhal, le Rouge et le Noir.

Comment: _La maison dont j'ai hérité de mon père._ est un peu biscornu. On a du mal  à comprendre du premier coup, de nos jours. Et pourquoi pas l'accord avec _dont_? Et puis, j'aurais dit: _la maison que j'ai héritée de mon père_.

Comment: Le bon usage de _dont_ est un peu [compliqué](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dont). Une tournure plus simple et plus claire (_La maison que j'ai héritée de mon père_) serait peut-être une première recommandation plus appropriée.

Comment: @Frank Oui, « dont … de » est inhabituel, mais ce que je voulais préciser, c'est qu'il n'y avait pas d'accord avec « dont ». J'ai étoffé ma réponse pour séparer la forme qui prête à controverse de celle que je voulais mettre en avant.

Comment: Merci. Bonne réponse.